# How to store more than 9 high-precision decimals in BigQuery with `bq load`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, geojson

I'm trying to `bq load` newline-delimited geojson files into BigQuery. It's working fine (even the `geometry` values are working correctly!) except when trying a high-precision number with more than 9 decimals. A key:values such as `"ShapeSTArea": 20263.3349609375` won't store as a `NUMERIC` according to the documentation, but also won't store as a `STRING`.

In my schema, first I tried a `NUMERIC` type, but I got

```
- query: Invalid NUMERIC value: 20263.3349609375 Field: ShapeSTArea;
Value: 20263.3349609375
```

This was confusing to me, but then I remembered that `NUMERIC` can't represent more than 9 decimals. And I can't use low-precision `FLOAT64` for obvious reasons. So then I changed the schema type to `STRING` and got

```
- Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row
starting at position 0: Could not convert value to string. Field:
ShapeSTArea; Value: 20263.3349609375
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why can't a value like `20263.3349609375` be stored as a `STRING`?
2. How am I supposed to store these high-precision numbers in bigquery with `bq load` (without using dataflow or other scripting)?

Answer (score 1):

Please report the issue about storing float JSON values into STRING table column to BigQuery - https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers. I think this should work.

You should be able to store this value in `FLOAT64` without data loss, `FLOAT64` has enough precision to store 15 decimal digits. JSON float values are typically 64-bit.

Alternatively, you can use BigNumeric type, which has higher precision than Numeric: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#decimal_types